# Undefined reference to `XF86VidModeQueryExtension'

Tags: cmake, makefile

I am trying to compile libfreenect2 from [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) and it turns out that when I run the make file after having done cmake CMakeLists.txt in step 5, I keep having the following errors:

```
Linking CXX executable /home/lex/libfreenect2/examples/protonect/bin/Protonect
/home/lex/libfreenect2/examples/protonect/lib/libfreenect2.so: undefined reference to `XF86VidModeQueryExtension'
/home/lex/libfreenect2/examples/protonect/lib/libfreenect2.so: undefined reference to `XF86VidModeGetGammaRampSize'
/home/lex/libfreenect2/examples/protonect/lib/libfreenect2.so: undefined reference to `XF86VidModeGetGammaRamp'
/home/lex/libfreenect2/examples/protonect/lib/libfreenect2.so: undefined reference to `XF86VidModeSetGammaRamp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/lex/libfreenect2/examples/protonect/bin/Protonect] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Protonect.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you execute `ccmake` (with 2 'c') command after your first `cmake` in order to access to the compilation options ?

Comment: No. I see no reason why I have to. The problem is unrelated to what you are thinking. Anyway, this was an opengl mesa utils issue which I fixed by installing mesa.

Answer (score 1):

Your program appears to depend upon libXxf86vm.  You will need to add something like

```
-lXxf86vm
```

to the link command line.  Be sure to install the development package. I am surprised the CMakeLists.txt did not have this.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/install.html) seems to fix my issue. It's something that probably had to do with the dependencies of libfreenect2 during the cmake installation.